# How can I prove that the derivative of $\sin(z)$ is $\cos(z)$ using the difference quotient formula?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I can write $\sin(z)$ in terms of $\sin(x+iy)= \sin(x)\cos(iy)+\cos(x)\sin(iy)$ where $\cos(iy)=\cosh(y)$ and $\sin(iy)=i\sinh(y)$.

Then I can apply $f'(z)=u_x +iv_x$ to get $\cos(z)$.

But how can I prove this using the difference quotient formula:
$$f'(z_0)=\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{f(z_0 +\Delta z)-f(z_0)}{\Delta z}$$

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(\cos z)':=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos (z+h)-\cos z}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\cos z\left(\cos h-1\right)-\sin z\sin h}h=$$

$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\cos z\frac{\cos h-1}h-\lim_{h\to 0}\sin z\frac{\sin h}h=0-\sin z \cdot1=-\sin z$$